# Unable to pass string containing current date and time in open() in Python

Tags: python, file, datetime

I'm trying to create a file whose name contains current date and time at the time of creation.

But it is giving me Invalid argument error when passing the string to open() function.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
import os, time
from datetime import datetime
# fname='Portals Statuses at '+datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')+'.txt'
# fname="Portals Statuses at "+time.strftime('%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')+".txt"
fl=open(fname,'w+')
```

No matter what value is passed to fname from above code, it is still throwing below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/preddy53/PycharmProjects/Practice/Status checks.py", line 7, in <module>
    fl=open(fname,'w+')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Portals Statuses at 2018-Aug-21 18:45:01.txt'
```

Comment: You cannot have file name with `:`

Comment: Colons are not valid in pathnames on Windows except in specific situations such as after the drive letter. They are legal on UNIX systems (modulo restrictions by the underlying filesystem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `.strftime()` call to replace `:` (which cannot be used in file names) with `.` or something else.

```
fname='Portals Statuses at '+datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%b-%d %H.%M.%S')+'.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I was having colon in file name **':'**